# BigQuery field has changed type from STRING to TIMESTAMP

Tags: python, google-bigquery, datetime-format

I'm importing data into BigQuery using Python API:

```py
import os
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud.exceptions import BadRequest
import json

from schema import schema


target_project_name = 'project_name'
target_dataset_name = 'dataset_name'
target_table_name = 'table_name'

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = './credentials.json'

dataset_ref = bigquery.dataset.DatasetReference(target_project_name, target_dataset_name)
table_ref = bigquery.table.TableReference(dataset_ref, target_table_name)

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
job_config.schema = schema

client = bigquery.Client()

cnt = 0

with open('./data/transformed_v2.json', 'r') as f:
    json_list = []
    for line in f.readlines():
        cnt += 1
        if cnt >= 10:
            break
        json_contents = json.loads(line)
        json_list.append(json_contents)


    job = client.load_table_from_json(json_list, table_ref)

try:
    result = job.result()
except BadRequest as ex:
    for err in ex.errors:
        print(err)
    print(job.errors)
```

The `schema` mentioned in the code above contains a problematic field `migration_datetime` that is defined as `bigquery.SchemaField("migration_datetime", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE")`. The field contains values that are stored in the `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S' format. The schema in the target table has the` migration_datetime`field specified as`STRING`.

The `job.result()` raises an error saying that `Field migration_datetime has changed type from STRING to TIMESTAMP`. To mitigate this, I added the `_string` suffix to values in the `migration_datetime` column but the error still occurs. Do you what may be the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider passing `job_config` into the `load_table_from_json` like [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-local#python) or using [client.schema_from_json](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.schema_from_json)

Comment: LOL. This was pretty easy and I was forgetting to pass the parameter. Thanks